# ExtJS 4.2 How to set grid filter height when header text is wrapped?

Tags: css, extjs, filter, grid, extjs4

I have a grid with many columns, each of them has a filter, and some of the columns has a long text in the header:

[image]

I added a css rule to wrap text in the header:

```
.x-column-header-inner .x-column-header-text { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

In result I got filters with different height:

[image]

How to make the same height filters?

Comment: How did you get these filter fields. I'm looking for this but didn't yet find.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer it's `triggerfield` added to items of a custom column.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that and hope to get it to work.

Comment: If my answer doesn't help you, consider adding some code in order to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue by including search filters into fieldcontainers, and using `vbox` layout with `pack` at the end.

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        layout: {
                    type: 'vbox', pack: 'end'
                },
        width: '100%',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'triggerfield',
                ...other code...
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the search filter with your hint. You can [find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014855/extjs-filter-a-grid-with-a-search-field-in-the-column-header). I didn't have your issue with long column labels. They just cut off using an ellipsis like it is the standard behavior in ExtJs.